# Vnc with WebRTC for remote screen control

Tags: node.js, encoding, webrtc, vnc, rfb-protocol

**Overview**

Is it possible to use VNC (RFB) with WebRTC to implement remote screen control using Node Js? I get remote screen frames from RFB and I want to transform it to MediaStream and then send to the client side. I was trying to search for any solution in the net but found nothing I can use.

**Possible solutions I've found**

1. ffmpeg frame encoding (I don't sure I can encode frames to something suitable for MediaStream)
2. put frames into canvas element and then capture to the MediaStream

**Main question**

How to encode rfb frames to be suitable for Mediastream and WebRTC

**What I've been using until now**

I just transform rfb frames to png pictures, send to the client and render it using canvas. Problem - poor fps, quite big latency

**Is there any other solutions except WebRTC?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think WebRTC is a great solution for this, this Open Source project [neko](https://github.com/nurdism/neko) does it already. They aren't using VNC (but instead using GStreamer to capture X11), but that totally possible to change.

Since png is lossless you are wasting a lot of bandwidth on that, if possible I would encode to VPx or H264.

Are you transporting these png via the DataChannel? I would also use RTP if possible. The browser will discard late frames (and other optimizations) to make sure you get the best experience.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yeah, I guess, h.264 is a great solution, but I haven't found any solutions to encode rfb frames to h.264. Is there anything? Also, I transporting pngs via socket connection

Comment: You can use GStreamer's rfbsrc maybe? That will take care of decoding, then you can encode to whatever you want!

Comment: Does using GStreamer to capture X11 also work to control Windows / macOS operating systems, like VNC?